# Tool to generate JUnit skeleton code, usable with JPA, JAX, CDI etc

Tags: software-development, java, unit-tests

I've got a largish Java EE project in Eclipse Kepler, and going through *New/Other/JUnit Test Case* for each file is not really something I want to do.

So, first I want to find a tool that will build these skeletons *en masse* - Google CodePro Analytix promised that, but it's a bit out of date. What do you recommend.

Secondly, and closely related, the project uses JPA, JAX, CDI, etc, etc, so I would need a lot of mocking or other techniques to perform unit tests; what do you recommend?

Comment: What platform(s) do you need it to run on?

Comment: I presumed the solution would be a Java program, so on anything. Preferred is Linux, second is Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [web site on automated testing](http://mit.bme.hu/~micskeiz/pages/code_based_test_generation.html) lists quite a few academic and commercial test case generators.  Unfortunately, I don't see any that generate test cases en masse.  Most, if not all, seem to generate tests for either one class or one method at a time.

Update:  Agitar's claims its [JUnit Generator](http://www.agitar.com/solutions/products/automated_junit_generation.html) can generate many unit tests quickly.  I don't know if it is current.  Most of the information seems old.